# Configure MSSQL 2008 to use kerberos authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, kerberos, jdbc

I would like to set my current mssql db (2008 and 2012) to authenticate using a linux kerberos server that I have in my environment .

The windows station is in a workgroup and I would like to avoid having to setup a domain controller and active directory .

How can I accomplish that ? what do I need to configure on the windows side and the kerberos server side (assuming it's configured already to work with other dbs running on linux based OSes) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is manageable. All you need is a trusted connection to an odbc connector and you can read about that here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568450.aspx

Comment: Thanks @robwahl for the answer. I need to configure it for jdbc which I did , but I'm getting some error message    
'Server not found in Kerberos database
Application/Function: Anything that makes a service ticket request.
Potential Causes and Solution: The account for the service principal name being requested doesn't exist in Active Directory or is incorrect in Active Directory. This could also indicate a DNS problem.'
any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're going to have to "trick" windows into natively authenticating against the linux kerberos server, which might be more effort than you're looking for.  Things I found include:

- [This O'Reilly article](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Linux_in_a_Windows_World/Centralized_Authentication_Tools/Kerberos_Configuration_and_Use#Windows_Kerberized_Clients)
- [PGina](http://pgina.org/plugins.html) is old and doesn't include Kerberos out of the box, but you
  could write a plugin (yikes).
- [Use SAMBA and FreeIPA to create a trust with your linux kerberos server](http://www.kerberos.org/events/2010conf/2010slides/2010kerberos_dmitry_pal.pdf)

Or, you could [use SQL Server authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) instead.